ERR_FAILED 413 (Payload Too Large) error in Vue.js
I am trying to send information with image attachements whereas when images are more than 10 MB the api fails with error "413 (Payload Too Large)". Please let me know how we can handle it .
submit() {
      const $this = this;

      var request = {
          studentnumber: this.studentnumber,
          dob: this.dob,
          details: this.details
      }
      this.loading = true;
      api.post('/api/studentinfo', request)
          .then(function (response) {
              const data = response.data;
            }
        }).catch(() => {
            $this.$toast.error($this.$t('Error'));
        }).finally(function () {
            $this.loading = false;
        });
}

config.js
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'Server',
            script: './server.js',
            instances: 'max',
            exec_mode: 'cluster',
            watch: false,
            env: {
                NODE_ENV: 'dev',
                PORT: process.env.PORT || 3000
            }
        },
        configureWebpack: {
            optimization: {
                splitChunks: {
                    minSize: 10000,
                    maxSize: 250000,
                }
            }
        }
    ]
};


You could inform the user that the payload is too large or if you have control over the server you could increase the max payload size.
What have you tried so far?

@kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze, I tried to check using chunk but nothing works

That’s up to your api service

Chunks here are about your Webpack bundle, not the payload you're sending, they are hence quite unrelated. Either increase the payload size on the backend or just skip sending such a big file from the client.

@kissu the payload size should be increased in Api C# code?

The payload size should be increased in the webserver configuration for the webserver used. It's not possible to tell from the question what backend technology is used
